# Is it possible to make vegetarian 'prawn' toast?

Tags: bread, vegetarian

As a vegetarian for over 15 years the only food I continue to miss is prawn toast. Does anybody whether it would be possible to make a vegetarian version and what alternatives to prawn could be used?

Answer (score 3):

This recipe seems to be something close to what you are looking for!
http://vegweb.com/index.php?topic=21443.0
Tofu seems to be a reasonable substitute.

However you can also find a vegetarian shrimp substitute through this company:
http://www.vegieworld.com/cart/product_pages.asp?id=667

One of their suggested preparation methods is for toast!

Comment: ooo that looks promising! I'd have to leave out the kelp seasoning. Do you think it would be possible to make with actual egg not egg replacement? Also are green onions the same as spring onions?

Comment: Nope, spring onions and green onions are different! http://www.harvestwizard.com/2008/05/spring_onions_green_onions_and.html Sorry, I changed my post at the last minute! I mention a site above that sells vegetarian shrimp substitute. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you that's really helpful. That website has a minimum order of $50 so I'm going to have to find a different source (and somewhere with UK delivery) but at least I know it's possible now!

Comment: @nixy: The kelp seasoning will probably be a large part of "the sea" taste.

Comment: That's a really good point, I haven't even heard of kelp seasoning before though so I may struggle to find it

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of vegetarian mock meats out there, but the availability is probably quite variable. May Wah has the largest selection of frozen mock meats I've ever seen and includes prawns: http://www.vegieworld.com/ You could probably use those in your recipe.